# Changing info.plist item title by user's purchase state

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have `Home Screen Shortcut Items` in my info.plist file. Depending on the user's purchase state of my app, I would like to change the title and subtitle of the home screen item. How to get purchase state with `if-else` in my code and change the title and subtitle of the `Home Screen Shortcut Items`?

Comment: check this doc on dynamic actions https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/menus_and_shortcuts/add_home_screen_quick_actions

Comment: That helped a lot.